# Parse String with delimiters to dictionary

Tags: c#, split, delimiter, string-parsing

I have a string formated so:

> string-int,string-int,string-int

The data will always be as above, what i need to accomplish is splitting each string-int value into a dictionary. Does anyone have an efficient solution to accomplish this?

As i understand it directly splitting the string by the ',' then splitting each result by the '-' into a dictionary is ineffcient.

Comment: Fine, what will be the expected key for the dictionary

Comment: "As i understand it directly splitting the string by the ',' then splitting each result by the '-' into a dictionary is ineffcient." Does that mean you've tried it and found that it doesn't meet your performance requirements? What exactly are those requirements?

Comment: I'd split on the comma and then the dash.  Don't know why you think that would be inefficient.  Only caveat would be if commas and dashes can be part of the string values.

Answer (score 4):

If you are absolutely assured that all data is correct you can use following:

- [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) source `string` to the `string[]` by "," symbol;
- for each element [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) it by "-" symbol;
- for each resulted element (of string[][]) [convert it to dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) pair. Use first element `[0]` as a key and [cast second element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.100).aspx) `[1]` to integer as a value;

  ```
  Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = sourceString
              .Split(',')
              .Select(element => element.Split('-'))
              .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => int.Parse(pair[1]));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try following .

```
  var input = "string-1,string2-2,string3-3";
  var splittedByComma = input.Split(',').ToList();
  var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  splittedByComma.ForEach(sp => dictionary.Add(sp.Split('-')[0], int.Parse(sp.Split('-')[1])));
```

Comment: Instead of `ForEach` why not use `ToDictionary`?

Comment: Thanks All, i had a rather more convulted way of splitting the data out, the 'list.ForEach' method above is far cleaner (readability wise), thanks tchelidze!

Comment: @DanHall Glad if it heped !

Answer (score 0):

```
static Dictionary<string, int> convert(string s)
    {
        var t = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        t.Add(s.Split('-')[0], System.Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('-')[1]));

        return t;
    }


var t = "\"test\"-123,\"test\"-123";

var d = t.Split(',').Select(convert);
```